# Uploading a picture to Windows Azure blob storage

Tags: c#, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to upload a picture to Windows Azure blob storage. I found a good example, but it relied on the `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient` assembly. I've just learned that the latest version of the Windows Azure SDK has a new `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage` assembly, which replaces the older `StorageClient` assembly. This new assembly uses new concreate types: `CloudPageBlob` and `CloudBlockBlob`. With the new assembly, I used the following:

```
// Setup the blob
string blobAddress = "myPicture.png";
CloudBlob blob = container.GetBlobReference(blobAddress);
blob.Properties.ContentType = "image/png";
```

With the new assembly though, I'm not sure what to use. If I'm uploading an image into blob storage, is it a page blob or a block blob? I don't understand the difference between the two. At the same time, I can't find information about the difference between the two. Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old library's CloudBlob.Upload* methods upload to block blobs. Hence, when updating your application to use the new library, you can use a CloudBlockBlob instead.

For more information on block blobs and page blobs, please refer to [Understanding Block Blobs and Page Blobs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee691964.aspx).