# AzureReader2 gives me a 400 Bad request when enabled

Tags: azure, imageresizer

My website is running on Azure with ImageResizer, AzureReader2 and DiskCache turned on. When I edit and deploy changes to the live website I get 400 Bad request errors on the website. If I disable AzureReader2 in Web.config the pages show up perfectly but obviously with the images missing. When I enable AzureReader2 the pages that I browsed earlier with AzureReader2 turned off work perfectly with the images being resized as expected, however the pages that weren't browsed give me a 400 Bad request. I've searched for a good day and a half for a solution but I haven't found anything that addresses this problem. Any idea on how I could resolve this for good would be awesome! Thanks.

Here's the test website: http://iwktest.azurewebsites.net/

```
Here's my diagnostics page:
Image resizer diagnostic sheet      6/23/2015 11:16:33 AM

0 Issues detected:


You are using plugins from the Performance Edition: DiskCache (Performance Edition), AzureReader2Plugin (Performance Edition)

Registered plugins:

ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.DefaultEncoder
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.NoCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.ClientCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.Diagnostic
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.SizeLimiting
ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.DiskCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.AzureReader2.AzureReader2Plugin

Configuration:

<resizer>
<pipeline fakeExtensions=".ashx" />
<plugins>
<add name="DiskCache" />
<add name="AzureReader2" connectionString="[redacted]" endpoint="http://iwkimages.blob.core.windows.net/" prefix="~/" />
</plugins>
</resizer>


Accepted querystring keys:

quality, format, thumbnail, maxwidth, maxheight, width, height, w, h, scale, stretch, crop, cropxunits, cropyunits, page, bgcolor, rotate, flip, sourceFlip, sFlip, sRotate, borderWidth, borderColor, paddingWidth, paddingColor, ignoreicc, frame, useresizingpipeline, cache, process, margin, anchor, dpi, mode, zoom, 

Accepted file extensions:

bmp, gif, exif, png, tif, tiff, tff, jpg, jpeg, jpe, jif, jfif, jfi, 

Environment information:

Running Microsoft-IIS/8.0 on Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0 and CLR 4.0.30319.36213
Trust level: Unrestricted
OS bitness: x86 !! Warning, running as 32-bit on a 64-bit OS(AMD64). This will limit ram usage !!
Executing assembly: D:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
IntegratedPipeline: True

Loaded assemblies:

mscorlib                                 Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.36213 Info: 4.0.30319.36213
System.Web                               Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.36283 Info: 4.0.30319.36283
System                                   Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.34239 Info: 4.0.30319.34239
System.Core                              Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.36213 Info: 4.0.30319.36213
System.Web.ApplicationServices           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.34248 Info: 4.0.30319.34248
System.Configuration                     Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.34209 Info: 4.0.30319.34209
System.Xml                               Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.36241 Info: 4.0.30319.36241
System.Runtime.Caching                   Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.17929 Info: 4.0.30319.17929
Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.17929 Info: 4.0.30319.17929
Microsoft.Web.Compilation.Snapshots      Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.1.0.0        
Microsoft.JScript                        Assembly: 10.0.0.0        File: 11.0.50709.17929 Info: 11.0.50709.17929
EnvSettings                              Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 46.0.8598.1007  Info: 46.0.8598.1007 (rd_websites_stable.150620-0845)
System.Web.WebPages.Deployment           Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.20105.407  
App_Code.tneplgwm                        Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
System.Data                              Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.34209 Info: 4.0.30319.34209
App_global.asax.wwlyy9nh                 Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
System.Web.Extensions                    Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.34248 Info: 4.0.30319.34248
System.ServiceModel.Activation           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.34209 Info: 4.0.30319.34209
Microsoft.CSharp                         Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.17929 Info: 4.0.30319.17929
System.Web.Services                      Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.34209 Info: 4.0.30319.34209
System.Drawing                           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.34209 Info: 4.0.30319.34209
System.EnterpriseServices                Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.17929 Info: 4.0.30319.17929
System.IdentityModel                     Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.34230 Info: 4.0.30319.34230
System.Runtime.Serialization             Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.34230 Info: 4.0.30319.34230
System.ServiceModel                      Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.36241 Info: 4.0.30319.36241
System.ServiceModel.Web                  Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.34209 Info: 4.0.30319.34209
System.Activities                        Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.34230 Info: 4.0.30319.34230
System.ServiceModel.Activities           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.17929 Info: 4.0.30319.17929
System.WorkflowServices                  Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.17929 Info: 4.0.30319.17929
System.Data.DataSetExtensions            Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.17929 Info: 4.0.30319.17929
System.Xml.Linq                          Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.17929 Info: 4.0.30319.17929
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations    Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.17929 Info: 4.0.30319.17929
System.Web.DynamicData                   Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.17929 Info: 4.0.30319.17929
ASPnetPagerV2_8                          Assembly: 2.8.3227.25225  File: 2.8.0.0        
Hyak.Common                              Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.2.0        
ImageResizer                             Assembly: 3.4.3.103       File: 3.4.3.103       Info: 3-4-3  Commit: bf92fd7
ImageResizer.Plugins.AzureReader         Assembly: 3.4.3.103       File: 3.4.3.103       Info: 3-4-3  Commit: bf92fd7
ImageResizer.Plugins.AzureReader2        Assembly: 3.4.3.103       File: 3.4.3.103       Info: 3-4-3  Commit: bf92fd7
ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache           Assembly: 3.4.3.103       File: 3.4.3.103       Info: 3-4-3  Commit: bf92fd7
Microsoft.Azure.Common                   Assembly: 2.0.0.0         File: 2.1.0.0        
Microsoft.Azure.Common.NetFramework      Assembly: 2.0.0.0         File: 2.1.0.0        
Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core            Assembly: 0.9.0.0         File: 0.9.1.0        
Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql           Assembly: 0.9.0.0         File: 0.29.0.0       
Microsoft.Data.Edm                       Assembly: 5.6.2.0         File: 5.6.2.61936     Info: 5.6.2.61936
Microsoft.Data.OData                     Assembly: 5.6.2.0         File: 5.6.2.61936     Info: 5.6.2.61936
Microsoft.Data.Services.Client           Assembly: 5.6.2.0         File: 5.6.2.61936     Info: 5.6.2.61936
Microsoft.Threading.Tasks                Assembly: 1.0.12.0        File: 1.0.168.0       Info: 1.0.168.0
Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.Desktop Assembly: 1.0.168.0       File: 1.0.168.0       Info: 1.0.168.0
Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions     Assembly: 1.0.12.0        File: 1.0.168.0       Info: 1.0.168.0
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration     Assembly: 2.0.0.0         File: 2.0.2.0        
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage           Assembly: 2.1.0.3         File: 2.1.0.3        
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient     Assembly: 1.7.0.0         File: 6.0.6002.18488 
Newtonsoft.Json                          Assembly: 6.0.0.0         File: 6.0.8.18111    
System.IO                                Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.17929 Info: 4.0.30319.17929
System.Net.Http                          Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.17929 Info: 4.0.30319.17929
System.Net.Http.Extensions               Assembly: 2.2.22.0        File: 2.2.22.0        Info: 2.2.22.0
System.Net.Http.Primitives               Assembly: 2.2.22.0        File: 2.2.22.0        Info: 2.2.22.0
System.Net.Http.WebRequest               Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.17929 Info: 4.0.30319.17929
System.Runtime                           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.34209 Info: 4.0.30319.34209
System.Spatial                           Assembly: 5.6.2.0         File: 5.6.2.61936     Info: 5.6.2.61936
System.Threading.Tasks                   Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.17929 Info: 4.0.30319.17929
System.Net                               Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.34209 Info: 4.0.30319.34209
System.Transactions                      Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.34209 Info: 4.0.30319.34209
System.ServiceModel.Internals            Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.34230 Info: 4.0.30319.34230
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime    Assembly: 2.6.0.0         File: 2.6.1198.712    Info: 2.6.1198.712 (rd_art_stable.150223-1353)
msshrtmi                                 Assembly: 2.6.0.0        
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.WebSites.Diagnostics Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 46.0.8598.1007  Info: 46.0.8598.1007 (rd_websites_stable.150620-0845)
Microsoft.Azure.Websites.StorageSdk      Assembly: 4.1.0.0         File: 4.1.0.0        
System.Web.RegularExpressions            Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.17929 Info: 4.0.30319.17929
SMDiagnostics                            Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.34230 Info: 4.0.30319.34230
System.Xaml.Hosting                      Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.17929 Info: 4.0.30319.17929
System.Xaml                              Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.34209 Info: 4.0.30319.34209
App_Web_3ugoikon                         Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
App_Web_hb2au1pk                         Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
App_Web_g5nsnuqc                         Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
App_Web_dzoq4fux                         Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
App_Web_wikwjgud                         Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
App_Web_jpawolt0                         Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
App_Web_i1ekkccj                         Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
App_Web_xk1ukx11                         Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
App_Web_iciotjon                         Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
App_Web_io0d5en1                         Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
System.Web.Mobile                        Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.34248 Info: 4.0.30319.34248
App_Web_fldm00ds                         Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
App_Web_jmu24pv1                         Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
System.Data.Services.Client              Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.17929 Info: 4.0.30319.17929

The following plugin assemblies are loaded but do not seem to be in use. You should remove them (and especially their dependencies (unless used elsewhere)) from the /bin folder to improve application load times:

ImageResizer.Plugins.AzureReader         Assembly: 3.4.3.103       File: 3.4.3.103       Info: 3-4-3  Commit: bf92fd7

Reference list of plugin dependencies - so you know what additional dlls to remove when removing a plugin. (may not be up-to-date, see plugin docs):

The FreeImage plugin has the following dependencies: FreeImage.dll and FreeImageNET.dll
The Logging plugin depends on: NLog.dll
The AdvancedFilters, RedEye, and WhitespaceTrimmer plugins depend on: AForge.dll, AForge.Math.dll, and AForge.Imaging.dll
The PsdReader and PsdComposer plugins depend on: PsdFile.dll
The S3Reader plugin depends on: LitS3.dll
The BatchZipper plugin depends on: Ionic.Zip.Reduced.dll
The PdfRenderer plugin depends on gsdll32.dll or gdsll32.dll
The RedEye plugin depends on several dozen files... see the plugin docs.
```

This is a glimpse of the web.config file

```
<plugins>
      <!-- For Image resizer image caching -->
      <add name="DiskCache" />
      <!-- Azure Blob reader   -->
      <add name="AzureReader2" connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=iwkimages;AccountKey=******" endpoint="http://iwkimages.blob.core.windows.net/" prefix="~/" />
    </plugins>
```

Answer (score 0):

This error means that `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient 1.7.0.0` is producing invalid requests to the Azure server. You should upgrade to a version 2.1 or higher, as older Azure libraries are no longer supported by Microsoft.

Comment: Hi Nathanael, I tried looking for a higher version but all I get is Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage which I upgraded to version 4.3.0.0 but no luck, it still shows the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient  as version 1.7.0.0. Any tips on how to update this. Thanks!

Comment: ImageResizer v4 requires the latest Azure libraries and will force them to be upgraded; you may try that route if you are unable to get the to upgrade via NuGet.

Comment: Hi Nathanel, sounds great. When will ImageResizer v4 be out. Will my current license still be valid for ImageResizer v4?

Comment: This post says that Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient assembly has been replaced by the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage assembly. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14442691/uploading-a-picture-to-windows-azure-blob-storage

Comment: Hi Rohan, your license is for v4; we stopped selling v3 on May 1st 2015.

Comment: Hi Nathanael,
I've upgraded to ImageResizer v4 but I still get the same Bad request errors as before and reproducible exactly with the same steps as before. 
Here's a copy of my diagnostic sheet:
http://iwkwestcoastus.azurewebsites.net/resizer.debug.ashx

I get the error on all pages that haven't been browsed with AzureReader2 turned on. Example below:
http://iwkwestcoastus.azurewebsites.net/Channels/News/

Comment: Could you provide an image URL? 

Also, why do you specify HTTPS as the default endpoints protocol, but then specify an http endpoint? Try dropping the endpoint configuration and letting it be created from your Azure account defaults.

Comment: I switched the default endpoints protocol to http but I still seem to be getting the same error. 
Image URL below:
http://iwktest.azurewebsites.net/articles/5755.jpg?width=280&height=180&mode=crop&anchor=topleft

Comment: You need to simplify your configuration, then re-introduce variables one-at-a-time. Don't override "prefix", that is a major complication.

Comment: I've cleaned up the configuration file of non essential variables. How do I prevent the 'prefix' from being overidden?

If I remove the prefix="~/" the page renders without the images, when I restore the prefix it works on the pages that were browsed but not on other pages.

Comment: I tried removing the endpoint configuration, I get the following error. This plugin needs a blob end point; the default will be [http|https]://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net.
Strangely all pages under a directory fail (http://iwktest2.azurewebsites.net/Channels/Columns/Default.aspx) but the same page under the root works perfectly (http://iwktest2.azurewebsites.net/test.aspx)

Comment: You can only drop the endpoint configuration on v4 and higher.

Comment: Upgraded to Version4 dropped the endpoint, unfortunately still the exact same error. Now if I have the prefix=~/ it gives me a 404 errors but once I drop that, it works again. Testing Version 4 with http://iwkwestcoastus.azurewebsites.net/resizer.debug.ashx gives an error : 'Could not load type 'ImageResizer.Util.BundleAttribute' from assembly 'ImageResizer, Version=4.0.0.0'

Comment: @Rohan You're mixing V3 and V4 assemblies. I'd suggest trying to access Azure Blobs directly with the Azure SDK, and perhaps that will give you enough information to contact Microsoft Support. I don't think I can help you further with this question via SO.